# How to create an array ordered by an alternated priority?

Tags: php, arrays

I've got an array with almost 50K+ sub_arrays. Put all of that in order by priority wasn't the problem, so I've managed to make it look like this:

```
$SendQueue = array(
    array('3', '+553400000001', 'My text messege here'),
    array('3', '+553400000002', 'My text messege here'),
    array('3', '+553400000003', 'My text messege here'),
    array('3', '+553400000004', 'My text messege here'),
    array('3', '+553400000005', 'My text messege here'),
    array('3', '+553400000006', 'My text messege here'),
    array('3', '+553400000007', 'My text messege here'),
    array('3', '+553400000008', 'My text messege here'),
    array('3', '+553400000009', 'My text messege here'),
    array('3', '+553400000010', 'My text messege here'),
    array('3', '+553400000011', 'My text messege here'),
    array('3', '+553400000012', 'My text messege here'),
    array('2', '+553400000013', 'My text messege here'),
    array('2', '+553400000014', 'My text messege here'),
    array('2', '+553400000015', 'My text messege here'),
    array('2', '+553400000016', 'My text messege here'),
    array('2', '+553400000017', 'My text messege here'),
    array('2', '+553400000018', 'My text messege here'),
    array('1', '+553400000019', 'My text messege here'),
    array('1', '+553400000020', 'My text messege here'),
);
//where '3', '2' and '1' are my priorities' types
```

What I really need is to alternate those sub_arrays, so they can look like this:

```
$SendQueue = array(
    array('3', '+553400000001', 'My text messege here'),
    array('3', '+553400000002', 'My text messege here'),
    array('3', '+553400000003', 'My text messege here'),
    array('3', '+553400000004', 'My text messege here'),
    array('3', '+553400000005', 'My text messege here'),
    array('3', '+553400000006', 'My text messege here'),
    array('2', '+553400000013', 'My text messege here'),
    array('2', '+553400000014', 'My text messege here'),
    array('2', '+553400000015', 'My text messege here'),
    array('1', '+553400000019', 'My text messege here'),
    array('3', '+553400000007', 'My text messege here'),
    array('3', '+553400000008', 'My text messege here'),
    array('3', '+553400000009', 'My text messege here'),
    array('3', '+553400000010', 'My text messege here'),
    array('3', '+553400000011', 'My text messege here'),
    array('3', '+553400000012', 'My text messege here'),
    array('2', '+553400000016', 'My text messege here'),
    array('2', '+553400000017', 'My text messege here'),
    array('2', '+553400000018', 'My text messege here'),
    array('1', '+553400000020', 'My text messege here'),
);
//Each 10 sub_arrays, 6 of them are priority '3', 3 of them are priority '2' and 1 of them is priority '1'
```

Does anyone know how to do that?

Comment: RTLM: http://php.net/usort

Comment: Between PHP's built in array functions and loops there isn't much you can't do with arrays. You just have to *try*.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/class.splpriorityqueue.php

Comment: looks like you need to build 3 different priority arrays, then pop 6 off priority 3, 3 off priority 2 and 2 off priority 1 into the results. Repeat this until all 3 are empty (only push onto results if pop is successful) NB you may need to use slice instead depending on your construction method

Comment: MarcB i would like to see your `usort` implementation ...

Answer (score 2):

You can try:

```
//Group the array
$group = array_reduce($SendQueue, function ($a, $b) {
    $a[$b[0]][] = $b;
    return $a;
});


$final = array();

while(count($final) < count($SendQueue)) {
    // 6 of them are priority '3'
    $final = array_merge($final, array_slice($group[3], 0, 6));
    // 3 of them are priority '2'
    $final = array_merge($final, array_slice($group[2], 0, 3));
    // 1 of them are priority '1'
    $final = array_merge($final, array_slice($group[1], 0, 1));
}

print_r($final);
```

[See Live Demo](http://eval.in/18016)

Comment: Nice & quick solution.. +1